# CWSAL0053E: The EBA file cannot be installed

Tags: ibm-infosphere

I was not able to execute `madconfig.sh redeploy_EBA`:

```
$ ./madconfig.sh redeploy_EBA
Buildfile: build.xml
Trying to override old definition of task executeUpdateScript

redeploy_EBA:
The osgi bundles will be redeployed at the following profile:
Cell Name: mdm-cell
Node Name: None
Server Name: None

#
# Wish to continue with OSGI bundles redeployment:
# Default Value: (yes)
yes

#
# Enter WAS password:
#


#
# Specify the MDM application password (default mdmadmin user):
#

Checking WebSphere Application Server details..
Trying to override old definition of task executeUpdateScript
Trying to override old definition of task executeUpdateScript

initialize_taskdef_libs:
Trying to override old definition of task EncryptDBPassword

check_server_status:
Trying to override old definition of task executeUpdateScript
Trying to override old definition of task executeUpdateScript

init:
Trying to override old definition of task CreateUser
Trying to override old definition of task EncryptDBPassword

uninstall_prop_file_jar:
[2017-10-02 16:37:04,962] [main] ERROR com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.core.MDMAppDeploy.deleteCompUnit(Line:?) - Failed from asyncCmdClientHelper.processCommandParameters(cmd).
[2017-10-02 16:37:04,966] [main] ERROR com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.core.MDMAppDeploy.deleteCompUnit(Line:?) - com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.OpExecutionException: CWWMH0221E: Composition unit ID cannot be empty or null.
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.commands.ADTCommand.finishOp(ADTCommand.java:320)
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.commands.ADTCommand.opCompleted(ADTCommand.java:428)
at com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.Operation.notifyListeners(Operation.java:170)
at com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.Operation.execute(Operation.java:242)
at com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.compound.CompoundOperation.execute(CompoundOperation.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.commands.ADTCommand$OperationScheduler.run(ADTCommand.java:672)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)

[2017-10-02 16:37:04,968] [main] ERROR com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.core.MDMAppDeploy.deleteCompUnit(Line:?) - Exception creating admin client: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.OpExecutionException: CWWMH0221E: Composition unit ID cannot be empty or null.
[2017-10-02 16:37:04,969] [main] ERROR com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.core.MDMAppDeploy.deleteCompUnit(Line:?) - java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.OpExecutionException: CWWMH0221E: Composition unit ID cannot be empty or null.
at com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.core.MDMAppDeploy.deleteCompUnit(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.core.configurator.ClusterMDMPropFileConfigurator.configure(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.remoteclient.command.ConfigMDMPropFileRemoteCommand.performUninstall(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.remoteclient.command.ConfigMDMPropFileRemoteCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.remoteclient.MDMRemoteClient.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mdm.de.ant.task.UninstallPropFileJarTask.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:382)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:107)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:123)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:123)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:123)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:150)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:240)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:282)
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.OpExecutionException: CWWMH0221E: Composition unit ID cannot be empty or null.
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.commands.ADTCommand.finishOp(ADTCommand.java:320)
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.commands.ADTCommand.opCompleted(ADTCommand.java:428)
at com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.Operation.notifyListeners(Operation.java:170)
at com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.Operation.execute(Operation.java:242)
at com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.compound.CompoundOperation.execute(CompoundOperation.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.commands.ADTCommand$OperationScheduler.run(ADTCommand.java:672)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)

[2017-10-02 16:37:04,982] [main] ERROR com.ibm.mdm.de.ant.task.UninstallPropFileJarTask.execute(Line:?) - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.OpExecutionException: CWWMH0221E: Composition unit ID cannot be empty or null.
at com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.core.MDMAppDeploy.deleteCompUnit(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.core.configurator.ClusterMDMPropFileConfigurator.configure(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.remoteclient.command.ConfigMDMPropFileRemoteCommand.performUninstall(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.remoteclient.command.ConfigMDMPropFileRemoteCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mdm.de.config.appserver.remoteclient.MDMRemoteClient.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mdm.de.ant.task.UninstallPropFileJarTask.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:382)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:107)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:123)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:123)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:123)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:150)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:240)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:282)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.OpExecutionException: CWWMH0221E: Composition unit ID cannot be empty or null.
... 56 more
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.OpExecutionException: CWWMH0221E: Composition unit ID cannot be empty or null.
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.commands.ADTCommand.finishOp(ADTCommand.java:320)
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.commands.ADTCommand.opCompleted(ADTCommand.java:428)
at com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.Operation.notifyListeners(Operation.java:170)
at com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.Operation.execute(Operation.java:242)
at com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.compound.CompoundOperation.execute(CompoundOperation.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.commands.ADTCommand$OperationScheduler.run(ADTCommand.java:672)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)


BUILD FAILED
/appl/IBM/MDMAE/mds/scripts/build-utils-postconfig.xml:893: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/appl/IBM/MDMAE/mds/scripts/build-utils-app.xml:1565: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.wsspi.management.bla.op.OpExecutionException: CWWMH0221E: Composition unit ID cannot be empty or null.

Total time: 31 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

The MDM was in some strange state and I had to stop WAS and for each profile I had to run `clearClassCache.sh` and `osgiCfgInit.sh` from profile's bin directory. After that I was able to redeploy EBA.

Comment: In my case I'm trying to run `madconfig Uninstall_MDM` and I'm getting this error. The .sh scripts didn't work in this case.

Comment: But I was having other issues earlier (the reason I'm uninstalling/reinstalling). If the reinstall doesn't fix it I might try the redeploy EBA and see if I get this same error and if clearing the cache doesn't help...